# IntegrationTest with SuperTest expects 302 gets 200 in Sails.js application

Tags: node.js, testing, sails.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm trying to write a simple Test for my Controller. I use this [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing) from Sails.js

The UserController.test.js:

```
var request = require('supertest');

describe('UserController', function () {

    describe('#login()', function () {
        it('should redirect to / indexpage', function (done) {
            request(sails.hooks.http.app)
                .post('/login')
                .send({name: 'Stifflers', password: 'Mom'})
                .expect(302)
                .expect('Location', '/', done);
        });
    });

});
```

The relevant code from AuthController.js:

```
...
   // is authenticated
      res.writeHead(302, {
        'Location': "/"
       });

       res.end(); 
...
```

I run the test with *npm test* and get this error:

> Error: expected 302 "Found", got 200 "OK"

When I change the *.expect(302)* in my test to *.expect(200)* I get the next error:

> Error: expected "Location" header field

I have tried to do it the same like in the documentation, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Why don't you use ```res.redirect(302, '/')``` ?

Comment: @Bonanza That doesn't matter, we get the same effect. 
1: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect
2: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's actually executing the correct route? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: I have in config/routes.js:   'post /login': 'AuthController.login',     And the above redirect is in AuthController.login() function.

Comment: omg, my fault... omg... my test password was not correct. It was everything just about that. But how could I find this dumb error earlier??? omg

Comment: actually I sent wrong post variables.

Answer (score 0):

call me dumb... the error was caused by the wrong post variables which I were sent.

```
            .send({email: 'Test@test.ch', password: 'test'})
```

I had to send **email** not name! Everytime I tested it with postman with "email", and in my code I had "name".

I saw there are a lot of similar questions on SO and elsewhere; Maybe my fault can help them to check their own code better.